# Hindu names for Muslim characters in "Master of None"

Tags: character, master-of-none

Why did Aziz Ansari choose Hindu names (Dev and his father Ramesh) for Indian Muslim characters in "Master of None"?

Answer (score 2):

It actually doesn't make sense at all. Maybe Aziz Ansari is trying to purvey himself in "Master of None," which is obviously sort of a biopic about his life, as being a New Age quintessential Desi in the Western world and what better way to present that than with Sanskrit-origin traditionally Hindu names, as all Desis are either Hindu or descended from Hindus, and would not be a genuine representation for all Desis with the Ansari family's Arabic-rooted commonly-Muslim names. Although this is somewhat of an untenable misrepresentation and and I would rather they use Arabic-rooted traditionally Muslim names and even their own as the show's Western audience maybe given more of a reason to assume the beliefs and origins of the Aziz Ansari's show family's names (Dev, Ramesh, Nisha) to be Islamic while the majority of the bearers of those names are brown-skinned Indian Hindus.  Also, I would just like to point out that the show is filled with inconsistencies about the family's origin as it is implied they are Tamil-speaking Muslims from an ethnic Tamilian-background while their names suggests Gujarati Hindu-origins.
P.S: If you want more of a Muslim perspective visit this links http://theaerogram.com/aziz-ansari-dev-shah-whats-name/