# Why Precious gave her baby a Muslim name?

Tags: plot-explanation, precious

In Precious (2009), Precious got raped by her own father & she gave a birth to second baby & she named him: **Abdul Jamal Jones**.

Precious family is purely **christian**.

Abdul itself sound like Muslim name without any googling.

Comment: From what I remember, she had a fairly horrible life. It's not too much of a stretch to assume she wanted to distance her baby from anything related to her life (Christianity, for instance).

Comment: ... "Abdul" to a lesser extent and "Jamal" are both somewhat common names in the African-American community, regardless of religion. I don't think there's any special meaning behind it.

Comment: "Abdul itself sound like Muslim name without any googling." Your prejudice is showing.  Abdul is indeed of Arabic origin, but Arabic is not the same as Muslim.

Comment: I asked this question after seeing this question: https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/73181/hindu-names-for-muslim-characters-in-master-of-none then my question is unclear that question not why?

Comment: @user52489 - primarily because you've made a massive assumption which comes across as somewhat prejudiced.  Perhaps you should do some googling after all.

Comment: It's not that assumption at all. Abdul is Arabic for "servant for god", and since Islam is a religion that claims God and all the arch angels speak Arabic and ONLY Arabic, it can therefore be concluded that any name derived from a Arabic religious phrase is therefore Muslim. The argument is inductive.

Comment: If I could add an answer, I would state that many blacks in some heightened sense of understanding or pursuit of escape or distinctness change their name to a Muslim one, just like Muhammad Ali did.

Comment: It's different because you're assuming that **only** Muslims use these names, which is simply untrue. Do a little research on the names... see examples of US people with them...

Comment: @Catija True, although US people can be Muslims :)